# adslot overlay-automatic inserting into page

Tags: css, ads, adsense

The below css snippet is auto inserting itself.
    .adslot-overlay {position: absolute; font-family: arial, sans-serif; 
(rest are omitted).
You can have a look in http://www.iiste.org/journals/index.php/ISEA

Can any one is having any suggestion why its happening like that.

Comment: Check it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985899/unwanted-css-injected-into-posts

Comment: I checked already.but there was no concrete answer for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10180134/1336699

Try disabling Google Publisher Toolbar in Chrome. That should fix it.